# Search a table with the result of another search in servlet

Tags: java, sqlite, servlets

I have a table **TABLE1** with 2 fields **id** and **shift** and another table **TABLE2** with 3 fields **id**, **name**, **surname**. The field id is the same an the primary key in both tables. 
In my servlet I want to select all the id's which have shift != noon. so I write

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT id FROM TABLE1 WHERE shifts!=NOON");
```

So i have gather all the records in **rs**. Now, How can I search through the second table in order to select the records with the id's i found in the 1st look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a join:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT t2.* 
                                  FROM TABLE1 as t1
                                  JOIN TABLE2 as t2
                                  ON t1.id = t2.id
                                  WHERE t1.shifts <> 'NOON'");
```

Look here:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Also you need to enclose strings like NOON inside single quotes 'NOON', and its best to use `<>` instead of `!=` as its standard `SQL` and more compatible with other databases.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ID, Name 
                                  FROM Table1
                                  INNER JOIN Table2
                                  ON Table1.ID=Table2.ID
                                  WHERE shifts!='NOON' ");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery
    ("SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE id in
        (SELECT id from Table1 WHERE shifts NOT LIKE 'NOON')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use join operator on SQL statements like in other answers,
or simply add every found id from first query to some ArrayList and then loop on every id in ArrayList and make second "SELECT *..." statment.

Join operation causes SQL server works slower than standard one table select, but if you have a lot of id from first statement, second one may take more time.